# Индексация сайта со скрытым контентом

Tags: javascript, html, css, поисковые-системы

Для облегчения поиска нужной пользователю информации была создана страница в которой каждая проблема представлена в виде категории (аналог меню), при клике на которую с помощью якорей пользователя переносит на нужную часть страницы, при этом как правило остальная часть страницы ему не нужна. Для облегчения восприятия было принято решение скрыть весь текст и оставить только кнопки с категориями и при нажатии на одну из них разворачивать только необходимый контент с помощью JS. Я знаю что на текст скрытый с помощью display:none плохо реагируют поисковые системы, поэтому задаюсь вопросом как лучше сделать скрытие текста? Мне в голову приходит мысль только с помощью JS после загрузки страницы скрывать, это приемлимо для меня, но все же как отреагируют поисковые системы на такое скрытие текста?

Answer (score 1):

В том же google.com/webmasters есть возможность посмотреть на странице как поисковый робот (Просмотреть как Googlebot). Рекомендую отлаживать страницу на нем.